# How to find out that the element does not have the attribute with certain value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, selenium, webdriver-io

In my webdriverIO script I need to assert that a table cell has a child element with attribute title="value1" and does not have a child element with title="value2". As for the first part of the task I use command

```js
expect(surveyCells[5].$('img')).toHaveAttr('title', 'Preview - Desktop Survey');
```

But what about the second part of the task where I need to assert that the element has no child element with title='Preview - Mobile Survey', something like this:

```js
expect(surveyCells[5].$('img')).doesNotHaveAttr('title', 'Preview - Mobile Survey');
```

Answer (score 0):

have you try:

```
expect(surveyCells[5].$('img')).not.toHaveAttr('title', 'Preview - Desktop Survey');
```